# Программа, которая делает javascript-код трудночитаемым

Tags: javascript

Я часто видел программы для разных языков, например, PHP, которые переименовывыют все переменные и функции в набор букв, убирают табуляцию и комментарии из кода и короче делают всё так, чтоб было трудно понять код. А какая есть такая программа для Javascript и где её скачать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это называется [сжатие и/или обфускация](http://javascript.ru/optimize/javascript-compression).
Мой выбор - [Closure-Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com)